# Have the Random functions changed?

Tags: random

I re-ran a program I wrote for Mathematica v8, now on v9, and it appears to generate different `RandomInteger` numbers, even though I use the same `SeedRandom` at the beginning.
Have Random functions changed in v9?

Comment: To give a particular example, what does `BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "ExtendedCA"]; 
 RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 10]]` return on version 9?

Comment: @J. M. - {4, -5, -7, -8, -3, -9, -5, -6, -1, 3}

Comment: hmmm. both v8 and v9 produce the same sequence for me...

Comment: You might find `ArrayReshape` better fitting your needs. There is an adequate example in its documentation.

Comment: @Artes - Thanks, I'll look at it. Any reason why it's better than Partition (which works now)?

Comment: @stevenvh `ArrayReshape` is new at `ver.9`, I can't answer precisely.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**The default random number generation method has changed from version 8 to version 9.**

The default methods for version 8 and version 9 are:

```
PRNG                |     v8           |  v9
-----------------------------------------------------
RandomInteger[]     |    ExtendedCA    |  Rule30CA
RandomReal[]        |    ExtendedCA    |  Rule30CA
```

The following does produce the same results for both versions:

```
methods = {
    "Congruential",
    "ExtendedCA",
    "Legacy",
    "MersenneTwister",
    "MKL",
    "ParallelGenerator",
    "ParallelMersenneTwister",
    "Rule30CA"
};

Table[BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> m]; 
      Print[m <> ": ", RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 10]]; 
      RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 10]], {m, methods}];


Congruential: {-9, 0, 3, -7, -9, -3, 5, -1, 7, 4}

ExtendedCA: {4, -5, -7, -8, -3, -9, -5, -6, -1, 3}

Legacy: {9, -9, 0, 5, 7, -5, 9, 8, -1, 0}

MersenneTwister: {7, 6, 5, 2, 0, -3, 4, 4, -1, 8}

MKL: {-5, 2, -8, -3, -3, -5, 1, 1, 3, -5}

ParallelGenerator: {-2, 2, 3, 0, -6, -7, 3, -7, -9, -1}

ParallelMersenneTwister: {-4, -4, -1, -2, 0, -9, 0, -8, -9, -8}

Rule30CA: {9, -9, 0, 5, 7, -5, 9, 8, -1, 0}
```

If you use the default method, you indeed get different results:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 10]]
```

v8:

```
{4, -5, -7, -8, -3, -9, -5, -6, -1, 3}
```

v9:

```
{9, -9, 0, 5, 7, -5, 9, 8, -1, 0}
```

If they claim that [the default is `"ExtendedCA"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SeedRandom.html#13671), than this is not true for version 9.
For version 9, the default is `"Rule30CA"`, while on version 8 it uses `"ExtendedCA"`.

So if you want to produce the same random numbers on version 9, you have to explicitly set the method to `"ExtendedCA"`.

Incidentally, the reason why `"Legacy"` and `"Rule30CA"` gave the same results for `RandomInteger` is that [the legacy method does use the rule 30 generator in the integer case](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/book/section-A.9.4#4.16).

---

**Now, let's test if this holds for `RandomReal` as well:**

```
Table[BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> m]; 
      Print[m <> ": ", InputForm @ RandomReal[10, 10]]], {m, methods}];

Congruential: {3.8461335440024715, 3.354304567149635, 4.51935934053208,
               8.850230228014308, 3.6248509154618356, 8.157875428939777,
               2.4513895134473387, 5.818949583945838, 4.969467831268059,
               0.03347488955145989}

ExtendedCA:   {4.259052837159626, 3.910231598741685, 3.4706935350965935,
               4.53740630685645, 5.5596334203812, 2.8916925336738952,
               2.9684806264504378, 2.064076444638916, 3.251697057830391,
               9.733246886114031}

Legacy:       {8.9572216046609, 4.970307857530802, 5.435846534404246,
               7.085955661473399, 6.776487260106322, 8.054379667584591,
               0.7094411741824413, 8.968322445752152, 8.901306909526046,
               0.7502088503156987}

MersenneTwister: {5.153950855950999, 0.6727671698455833, 4.524316138874237,
                  9.921991209186388, 0.5443991248015738, 8.437734478961886,
                  6.959208913527714, 9.091869760437504, 2.310061068071903,
                  8.976972757532419}

MKL:          {2.2010771720728672, 5.882083584870089, 0.7266383901861087,
               3.3726500591458435, 3.3079876451216217, 2.488652193017376,
               5.6151582821198005, 5.305289374386305, 6.735427495488978,
               2.29022838609706}

ParallelGenerator: {2.8013742426114714, 8.147026088771263, 3.8405810263728526,
                    2.5308472947817595, 9.400530227458631, 9.054157508803371,
                    9.449607002369156, 4.3141703917759315, 6.087645635734276,
                    6.8637216165050745}

ParallelMersenneTwister: {9.999076480701376, 9.830697737962758, 8.382728461259866,
                          9.292582323124666, 0.487553230365652, 5.914364713788565,
                          1.6141971841606058, 1.4211558070777137, 9.501590480279376,
                          2.6447011005402707}

Rule30CA:     {5.633636625848604, 0.19140585740303528, 6.149388826993686,
               1.9144953965106026, 2.9253076004819345, 0.55162786941208,
               1.995816904778028, 9.427477798414383, 0.39607049447435116,
               1.8220850707267502}
```

Both lists are identical between version 8 and version 9.

Let's use the default method for `RandomReal`:

**v8:**

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; InputForm @ RandomReal[10, 10]]

{4.259052837159626, 3.910231598741685, 3.4706935350965935,
 4.53740630685645, 5.5596334203812, 2.8916925336738952,
 2.9684806264504378, 2.064076444638916, 3.251697057830391,
 9.733246886114031}
```

So the default method for version 8 is `"ExtendedCA"`.

**v9:**

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; InputForm @ RandomReal[10, 10]]

{5.633636625848604, 0.19140585740303528, 6.149388826993686,
 1.9144953965106026, 2.9253076004819345, 0.55162786941208,
 1.995816904778028, 9.427477798414383, 0.39607049447435116,
 1.8220850707267502}
```

And the default method for version 9 is `"Rule30CA"`.

Comment: Huh, that's a step back. Here I thought they replaced the legacy generator with the newer CA-based ones precisely because the legacy method had not too good statistical properties...

Comment: I've hade the same 'yikes!' moment...in chess something like this would've been called a blunder.

Comment: Well, for completeness' sake, could you also do tests replacing `RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 10]` with `RandomReal[1, 10]`? Maybe use `InputForm[]` so that all the digits of the random variates are displayed... BTW, to cover the default method in the results of the `Table[]`, you can use the setting `Method -> Automatic`.

Comment: @J. M. done. if you want to have a look at it and feel free to improve things. btw. i've used coloured Grid's in my notebook, but it seems to be impossible to paste this here in SE, that's why i've used Table.

Comment: Actually, digging deeper into old docs, it would seem that [the legacy method in fact uses the rule 30 cellular automaton in the integer case](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/book/section-A.9.4#4.16). This is borne out by the fact that `"Legacy"` and `"Rule30CA"` give identical results for `RandomInteger[]`. In short, version 8 uses `"ExtendedCA"` as the default, while version 9 uses `"Rule30CA"` by default, for both random integers and reals. Now we wait for somebody from WRI to explain this switch...

Comment: @J. M. excellent. could you update the post to document that fact? But this doesn't hold for RandomReal!

Comment: @J. M. thanks for your edits...now this looks more professional and cogent indeed...

Comment: No problem; I couldn't contribute much otherwise since I'm not using a machine with *Mathematica* at the moment...

Comment: @"Now we wait for somebody from WRI to explain this switch..." Well, there was no switch.

Answer (score 3):

The default random number generation method has been the same for the last 12 years (in terms of releases, since V6).

It has not changed, certainly not between V8 and version V9, or more recently.

Both version 8 and version 9 should be using `"ExtendedCA"` as documented.

On my machine, both of the following results are as expected

```
In[1]:= $Version

(* 9.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (November 20, 2012) *)

In[2]:= BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 10]]

(* {4, -5, -7, -8, -3, -9, -5, -6, -1, 3} *)

In[3]:= BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; InputForm @ RandomReal[10, 10]]

(* {4.259052837159626, 3.910231598741685, 3.4706935350965935, 
    4.53740630685645, 5.5596334203812, 2.8916925336738952, 
    2.9684806264504378, 2.064076444638916, 3.251697057830391, 9.733246886114031} *)
```

I have tried the other platforms as well.

No idea what was happening in the earlier answer which claims `"Rule30CA"` was the default in V9, but it doesn't even seem possible.

I would think either a (mysterious!) bug, or some user initialization code switching the method.