# What pseudo-random number generators are available to Mathematica users?

Tags: random, undocumented

One would think I should be able answer the question I pose in the title for myself by reading the Documentation Center article ref/SeedRandom, but it's not so simple.

That article does give a list of generators, namely

- "Congruential", "ExtendedCA", 'Legacy", "MersenneTwister", "MKL", "Rule30CA"

#### Generators offered by the auto-completion system

One, of course, tells *Mathematica* which pseudo-random number generator to use by giving the `Method` option to `SeedRandom`. If I avail myself of the auto-completion facility, I can get the following four completions for the `Method` option of `SeedRandom`. I tried all of them.

```
SeedRandom[Method -> "MersenneTwister"]; (* works *)
SeedRandom[Method -> {"Sobol", "Dimension" -> 2}]; (* does not work *)
SeedRandom[Method -> {"MKL", Method -> "MCG59"}]; (* works *)
SeedRandom[Method -> {"Niederreiter", "Dimension" -> 2}]; (* does not work *)
```

I believe the two completions that don't work indicate a bug in the files supporting the auto-completion algorithm, but that's not the issue here. What's relevant here is the generator, {"MKL", Method -> "MCG59"}. Is this generator in any way distinct from "MKL"?

#### Generators suggested by `SeedRandom::nogen`

A `SeedRandom` call specifying an invalid generator method emits the message `SeedRandom::nogen` which offers the user a helpful list of valid generators, namely

- "ParallelGenerator", "Lattice", "Congruential", "ParallelMersenneTwister", "MersenneTwister", "MKL", "Rule30CA", "Rule50025CA', "ExtendedCA", "Legacy"

This list contains generators not offered by auto-completion and even some not mentioned in the Documentation Center articles ref/SeedRandom and tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration. It even mentions some not mentioned in the answers to a [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27408/3066).

#### Are there more?

I'm left wondering if there are still more pseudo-random number generators than the ones I uncovered during my little adventure with the `Method` option of `SeedRandom`.

Comment: [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html#185956823)

Comment: @ciao. Nice reference. Adds a goodly amount of supporting material, but does not answer my question.

Comment: Am I missing something? Isn't "... wondering if there are still more pseudo-random number generators..." the question?

Comment: @ciao. I've read the article you cite. It doesn't contain a complete list of the built-in generators. For example, it doesn't mention "Lattice", so why should I consider it definitive?

Comment: Fair enough, removing CV

Comment: Your use of `"Niederreiter"` and `"Sobol"` look incorrect - in @ciao's link they are in fact sub-methods of `"MKL"`?

Comment: @blochwave. Yes, they are incorrect, but they are you get with auto-completion. They are sub-methods of "MKL". As I said in the question, it's a bug in the auto-completion, but that bug is not an issue for this question. The only reason I mention these buggy completions is because they emitted `SeedRandom::nogen` which gave the 2nd, longer list of generators and which reveals further undocumented generators.

Comment: @m_goldberg, sure ok, I understand!

Comment: @m_goldberg also, not built-in, but JM answered this for me for another generator: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91497/implementing-the-pcg-random-number-generator

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, there are no more built-in generators.

In this case, the `SeedRandom::nogen` message can be regarded as definitive. The list it prints is not predefined, but a runtime enumeration of all existing system random number generators.

A couple of these are indeed undocumented: `"Rule50025CA"` is cellular automaton based and similar to `"ExtendedCA`" but using a different rule; `"Lattice"` is intended for internal use by `NIntegrate`'s `"MonteCarloRule"` for generating lattice random points (it is not the default as far as I know, but can be requested via the `"PointGenerator"` suboption).

The code completion mix-up of methods and method suboptions is a bug; it could also offer completions for the other documented methods, not just `"MKL"` and `"MersenneTwister"`. I will follow-up on this so it can be fixed (**update: fixed in 10.4.0**).

For the remaining question,

> What's relevant here is the generator, {"MKL", Method -> "MCG59"}. Is this generator in any way distinct from "MKL"?

[MCG59](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/590403) is one of several different generators implemented in the Intel MKL library. This setting is distinct from using just `"MKL"` which defaults to [MRG32k3a](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/590402).

Comment: Judging from the name I would have guessed that `"Lattice"` is used in `"QuasiMonteCarlo"`. But I have not looked at the code and that's just a guess.